# How do I change the class name of element "B" onFocus element "A"

Tags: javascript, css, onfocus

I'm building an accessible site to play YouTube videos for people with disabilities. I'm using onfocus (and changing classnames) rather than use :focus so that its compatible with more browsers to give visual feedback on the link selected.

I'd like to style the list item background when a text/img link gets keyboard focus - is this possible?

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: Please note: the site is to be used by students with visual impairment, so only using keyboard input (usually tab & enter). Therefore, I need the style of the <li> to change when keyboard focus is brought to the text / img links. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `<li>` can get (keyboard) focus programmatically, but I can [show you how to change classnames](http://jsfiddle.net/YdKtz/1/) programmatically.

[**edit** based on comment] If it's hrefs you mean, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PgMcL/) is a working example. Use tab to jump to the next href.

```js
"use strict";  
(function () {

  var refs = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
  document.addEventListener('focus', hoverClass, true);

  refs[0].focus();
  setTimeout(emulateHover, 800);

  function emulateHover() {
     if (!document.activeElement.href) {return clearTimeout(0);}
     var index = parseInt(document.activeElement.href.split(/#/)[1], 10);
     var activeElement = refs[index] || refs[0];
     if (activeElement) { activeElement.focus(); }
     setTimeout(emulateHover, 800);
  }

  function hoverClass(evt){
      var srcEl = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
      var i = refs.length;
      while(i--) { refs[i].className = 'a'; }
      if (srcEl && !/a/i.test(srcEl.tagName)) { return clearTimeout(0); }
      var isA = /a$/i.test(srcEl.className);
      srcEl.className = isA ? 'b' : 'a';
  }
  
}());
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial;
}
.a {background-color: #eee; transition: all 0.5s 0s}
.b {background-color: green; color:white; transition: all 0.5s 0s}
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a id="first" class="a" href="#1">line 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#2">line 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#3">line 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#4">line 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#5">line 5</a></li>
    <li><a class="a" href="#6">line 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration, however I need it to work when keyboard focus is brought to the text/img links as the site is to be used by students with visual impairment. Thanks for the input

Comment: The idea is exactly the same. I have cooked up a new example demonstrating that. See edits in my answer.

Comment: You should include the code in the answer instead of linking to it.

Comment: @FranciscoR satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

to set a new value of the class you can do:

```
element.className = "A";
```

if you use jQuery you can:

```
$(element).addClass("A");
$(element).removeClass("B");
```

Comment: so in the example of a <li> element - would I use: <li class="A"><a href="#" onfocus="javascript: li.className = 'B';" onblur="javascript: li.className = 'A';">textlink</a></li> ? How would this work with multiple <li> tags on a page?

Comment: do not use event attributes, it's hard to read and also event attributes are deprecated in xHtml. make a separate js file and create event handlers for your li elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it sounds nice to use focus (never tried if it works) for such HTML elements like list. Instead use hover.

I would go with following ; hover, mouseenter, mouseover.

```
$("ul.someclass > li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("current");
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
  });
```

For more information;

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: I need to use focus as the site will be used by students with visual impairment, so just using keyboard input. I don't think this will work as you the keyboard can only to text / img links. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Do you have a sample page where could see it? I'm no jquery expert, but I can try to help you out if I could see what you really want.

Comment: http://access.mwjt.co.uk/IBM - I need to style the divs of the 4 links at the bottom and subsequently the results page using onfocus. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a messy method that seems to work ok:

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$js  =  "<script language=\"javascript\">";
$js .=  "function changeClass$id(){";
$js .=  "document.getElementById(\"$id\").setAttribute(\"class\", \"popfocus\");}";
$js .=  "function changeClass1$id(){";
$js .=  "document.getElementById(\"$id\").setAttribute(\"class\", \"pop\");}";
$js .=  "</script>";

echo $js;
echo "<li><div id=\"$id\" class=\"pop\">\n";
echo "<a 

onFocus=\"changeClass$id()\" 
onBlur=\"changeClass1$id()\"
onMouseover=\"changeClass$id()\" 
onMouseout=\"changeClass1$id()\"
```